# TeX live 2012 full installation on gentoo linux

Tags: installing, texlive, linux

What is the "gentoo-way" to install the latest full TeX live collection?
I know the tex live installer script to install the complete collection manually, but I would prefer to "emerge" a gentoo package.

I could not find a meta package like `virtual/texlive-full` yet. Some gentoo packages contain plenty LaTeX packages other contain some only one package (like ucs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember correctly from my gentoo days, the correct package is simply `app-text/texlive`, but you have to set all the `USE` flags to get the entire collection.  The list of the USE flags is long, check out [texlive-2012.ebuild](http://sources.gentoo.org/viewcvs.py/gentoo-x86/app-text/texlive/texlive-2012.ebuild?view=markup).

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to install TeX-Live directly from tug.org. It is possible for every user, you can have different installations parallel available (2011 and 2012 for instance). In the past, I detect a very old package included in one of the Gentoo portage collection.